# Use variables/lists as an autocmd pattern

Tags: list, variables, vim, autocmd

Is it possible to use variables or lists to pass patterns to vim's autocmd?

Here is an example:

```
" Automatically source .vimrc if there have been any changes
let candidates = [ ".vimrc", "_vimrc", "vimrc", ".gvimrc", "_gvimrc", "gvimrc" ]

augroup AutoSourceVimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost candidates so $MYVIMRC | if has('gui_running') | so $MYGVIMRC | endif
augroup END
```

The example above does not work - unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler version of your command:

```
augroup AutoSourceVimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost *vimrc execute "source " . expand("<afile>")
augroup END
```

Comment: That is a good workaround! However I assume autocmd does not expand variables containing patterns?

Comment: That is not a workaround, using a pattern is how you are supposed to do it.